# CodeBlocks - Irrlight compilation/run Error

Tags: compiler-errors, ide, linker-errors, irrlicht

I just receive this error after I compiled the Irrlicht Project in Codeblocks. 
Here is the Error Screenshot:
http://1drv.ms/1jcDdIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recompile the Irrlicht.dll library. There is a .cbp project that will compile it. Then replace the provided dll by you new one. I had the exact same problem so I am sure this will solve yours.